# Upload youtube videos with out user credentials

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm planning to develop a web app where user can upload videos. I have done that with Youtube APIs, but the problem is upload is working only with my credentials because of my client ID. Is there any way to upload videos without my credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with service accounts, which are robot accounts that identify machines rather than users. First, [create a service account and key in Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/permissions/serviceaccounts). Then, add the service account's email address as a [manager of the YouTube channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007). Finally, you can make the API call using the service account's private key. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) for a code example.